# How to have a set of sets in Python?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, set

In Python there's no full support for heterogeneous data structures. For example this fails:

```
set(set(1,2),set(2,3))
```

What's the best way to treat sets of sets?

Comment: I think your example fails for two reasons. #1 because the set constructor only takes one argument and #2 because sets are mutable and therefore unhashable. You could fix #2 by using the immutable frozenset and #1 by using set literals or wrapping the elements in a list.

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake I think that deserves to be an answer.

Comment: @athan Perhaps, but two people already beat me to it :P

Answer (score 55):

Use [frozenset](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset),

```
>>> set([frozenset([1,2]), frozenset([2,3])])
set([frozenset([1, 2]), frozenset([2, 3])])
```

---

To represent a set of sets, the inner sets must be **frozenset** objects for the reason that the elements of a set must be **hashable** (all of Python’s *immutable* built-in objects are *hashable*). `frozenset` is *immutable* and `set` is *mutable*.

Answer (score 6):

You can't have a set of sets in the usual sense but if you can work with [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) objects then it can work:

```
>>> set([set([1,2]), set([3,4])])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

This does work:

```
>>> set([frozenset([1,2]), frozenset([3,4])])
set([frozenset([1, 2]), frozenset([3, 4])])
```

Answer (score 2):

There is good reason why a set of sets does not work. Imagine the following (in pseudocode):

```
a = set(range(5))   # {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
b = set(range(5, 10))  # {5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
c = set(range(5))  # {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
# we've now created a set of sets, and then will drop `c` because it's redundant
d = set([a, b, c])  # {{0, 1, 2... }, {5, 6, 7...}}
# now we've changed a value inside the set, suddenly everything changes
a.add(6)     # {{0, 1, 2..., 6}, {5, 6, 7...}}
# now we can re-add `c`
d.add(c)    # {{0, 1, 2..., 6}, {5, 6, 7...}, {0, 1, 2...}}
```

Besides the weird behavior of how elements would suddenly disappear, or act differently if they were mutable, there is also the lack of hash-based lookups.

The set implementation is very similar to the dict implementation, and can be found [here](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Objects/setobject.c?view=markup). This is the implementation if a set contains a given key. Notice how it calculates the hash of the object, finds the first occurrence, and then does a lookup from the hash?

```
static int
set_contains_key(PySetObject *so, PyObject *key)
{
    long hash;
    setentry *entry;

    if (!PyString_CheckExact(key) ||
        (hash = ((PyStringObject *) key)->ob_shash) == -1) {
        hash = PyObject_Hash(key);
        if (hash == -1)
            return -1;
    }
    entry = (so->lookup)(so, key, hash);
    if (entry == NULL)
        return -1;
    key = entry->key;
    return key != NULL && key != dummy;
}
```

Now, if we modify `a` in the example above, how do we perform a lookup? The only solution would be item-by-item lookups, which would have O(n) time complexity.

Fortunately, there is an easy solution shown above: an immutable set. Fortunately, Python even has this builtin, the [frozenset](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset).

With a frozenset, since it is immutable, a hash can be calculated, both preventing unexpected behavior, but also restoring our O(1) lookups.

In this case, we can do the following:

```
a = frozenset(range(5))
b = frozenset(range(5, 10))
c = frozenset(range(5))
d = set([a, b, c])
```

And now, `d` will allow membership lookup on individual items, with solely discrete containers, since the frozenset members are immutable.

Comment: This code errors as it should. Fake news

Comment: In your example, I would expect `add(6)` to add a singlet set `{6}` to the outer set of sets, not to each of the inner sets, which would then not lead to the paradox you are describing.