# Python - wild grouping of friends

Tags: python, set

I generated a `dict` with about 60×10<sup>6</sup> elements:

```py
friends = {
    'aaron': {'john'},
    'bob': {'john'},
    'amy': {'gael', 'joe'},
    'gael': {'amy'},
    'joe': {'amy', 'patrick'},
    'john': {'aaron', 'bob'},
    'patrick': {'joe'}
}
```

I need to group the friends, the friends of the friends, the friends of the friends of the friends, etc... And get an equivalent of:

```py
groups = {
    {'aaron', 'john', 'bob'},
    {'amy', 'gael', 'joe', 'patrick'}
}
```

My approach would be to join all the `sets`:

```py
for n1 in friends:
    for n2 in list(friends[n1]):
        if not friends[n1] is friends[n2]:
            friends[n1].update(friends[n2])
            friends[n2] = friends[n1]
```

Which results in:

```py
friends = {
    'aaron': {'bob', 'aaron', 'john'},
    'bob': {'bob', 'aaron', 'john'},
    'amy': {'patrick', 'gael', 'joe', 'amy'},
    'gael': {'patrick', 'gael', 'joe', 'amy'},
    'joe': {'patrick', 'gael', 'joe', 'amy'},
    'john': {'bob', 'aaron', 'john'},
    'patrick': {'patrick', 'gael', 'joe', 'amy'}
}
```

And then get the unique sets out of it:

```py
groups = set()
for n in friends:
    groups.add(friends[n])
```

But that isn't permitted:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

I have to say, the whole method feels lacking when you consider the size of the input; I'm sure there is a better way to do the task. Could someone point me out in the right direction?

Comment: create a `frozen_set` that is hashable

Comment: The overall problem is finding *cliques*, and is generally thought of as a graph algorithm. The `networkx` third-party library is often recommended here, and there is more research you can do about DIY algorithms. However, for the question you actually asked, about deduplicating the results from your approach, that is a common issue and I've found you a duplicate for it.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thank you for the comment. It is indeed a simple Graph problem, I'll take a look at `networkx`. On the other hand, I don't think that `frozen_set` is the right tool for sets that can be tested with `is`.

Comment: As described, the sets can't be tests with `is`, because you can have multiple separate set objects that contain identical elements. In your algorithm, you start with distinct sets as the dict values, and populate them such that some of them are duplicated. However, if you *could* solve the problem by testing with `is`, then you could instead simply deduplicate *the `id()`s* of the objects (since these uniquely identify objects during their lifetime).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just walk the groups from the friends dictionary until no new friends for the current group

```py
friends = {
    'aaron': {'john'},
    'bob': {'john'},
    'amy': {'gael', 'joe'},
    'gael': {'amy'},
    'joe': {'amy', 'patrick'},
    'john': {'aaron', 'bob'},
    'patrick': {'joe'}
}

groups = []

visited = set()

for friend in friends:
  if friend in visited: continue
  currentgroup = set()
  todo = set()
  todo.add(friend)
  while todo:
    f = todo.pop()
    currentgroup.add(f)
    visited.add(f)
    todo = todo.union(friends[f]).difference(visited)
  groups.append(currentgroup)

for g in groups
  print(g)
```

Output

```
{'bob', 'aaron', 'john'}
{'amy', 'gael', 'joe', 'patrick'}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
friends = {
    'aaron': {'john'},
    'bob': {'john'},
    'amy': {'gael', 'joe'},
    'gael': {'amy'},
    'joe': {'amy', 'patrick'},
    'john': {'aaron', 'bob'},
    'patrick': {'joe'}
}

def get_friends(person, friendlist):
    ## Recursively get all of a person's friends
    friendlist.add(person)
    for p in friends[person]:
        if p not in friendlist:
            friendlist.update(get_friends(p, friendlist))
    return friendlist
    
def friend_set(friends):
    groups = set()
    parsed_friends = set()  
    for k, v in friends.items():
        if k not in parsed_friends:
            group = {k}
            for person in v:
                group = get_friends(person, group)
            groups.add(frozenset(group))
            parsed_friends.update(group)
    return groups

print(friend_set(friends))
# Result: {frozenset({'john', 'aaron', 'bob'}), frozenset({'amy', 'patrick', 'gael', 'joe'})}
```

Same idea as the other answer using a recursive function to assemble each friend list and checking already visited friends to save some time. This also uses a [frozenset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37105696/how-to-have-a-set-of-sets-in-python) (immutable set) for the inner friend groups because a set is mutable and must contain immutable items.

Comment: in the 60e6 friends problem this might reach the recursive limit